# when I run my network. I got an error,one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

Tags: python, pytorch

This is a part of code in my `train.py`:

```
output_c1[output_c1 > 0.5] = 1.
output_c1[output_c1 < 0.5] = 0.

dice = DiceLoss()
loss = dice(output_c1,labels)
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-78553e2886de>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('F:/experiment_code/U-net/train.py', wdir='F:/experiment_code/U-net')
  File "D:\pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "D:\pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "F:/experiment_code/U-net/train.py", line 99, in <module>
    loss.backward()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", line 107, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 93, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [4, 2, 224, 224]], which is output 0 of SigmoidBackward, is at version 2; expected version 0 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

When I comment this two lines of code:

```
output_c1[output_c1 > 0.5] = 1.
output_c1[output_c1 < 0.5] = 0.
```

it can run. I think the error comes from here but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`output_c1[output_c1 > 0.5] = x` is an inplace operation, meaning that it modifies directly the tensor instead of returning a modified copy. Hence it makes the computation of the gradient impossible.

To solve your usecase, you could use the function [`torch.round`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.round) to binarize your output :

```
binary_output_c1 = torch.round(output_c1)
# and don't forget to change the computation of your loss function!
dice = DiceLoss()
loss = dice(binary_output_c1,labels)
```